# Compare two list with multiple index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two list

```
list1 = [(('idA1_1','idA2_1'),('idB1_1','idB2_1')),(('idA1_2','idA2_2'),('idB1_2','idB2_2'))]
list2 = [(('idA1_1','idA2_1'),('idB1_1','idB2_1')),(('idA1_2','idA2_2'),('idB1_2','idB2_2'))]
```

I want to compare 'idA2_1' and idB2_1 in list1 to 'idA2_1' and idB2_1 in list2

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What do you expected for output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't think this is exactly what you're after, but it should be a good start.

```
list1 = [(('idA1_1','idA2_1'),('idB1_1','idB2_1')),(('idA1_2','idA2_2'),('idB1_2','idB2_2'))]
list2 = [(('idA1_1','idA2_1'),('idB1_1','idB2_1')),(('idA1_2','idA2_2'),('idB1_2','idB2_2'))]

print(list1[0][0][1] == list2[0][0][1])
print(list1[0][1][1] == list2[0][1][1])
```

Basically you've got a list of tuples which they themselves contain tuples. So the first set of square brackets access the top level tuple within the list, the second set access the nested tuple, and the third set the element in that nested tuple.